How to access MAUI asset file on iOS?
I am embedding files in my MAUI app, and succesfully access it at run-time on Android and Windows, but not on iOs (physical phone). Is there something I am missing or is there a bug I am not aware of ?
I embedd the file to the project lik like so:
  <ItemGroup>
    <MauiAsset Include="Resources\TextFile1.txt" />
  </ItemGroup>

I access it like so:
using (fileStream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("Resources/TextFile1.txt"))

Please note that:
var result = Directory.EnumerateFiles(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory);
var result = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory);

Return nothing on iOs, and that the splash screen and the icon of my app are replaced with the default one even though they work fine on other platforms.

AppDataDirectory will always be empty unless you write something to it at runtime.  Assets are embedded as part of the app package

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/hot-restart?view=net-maui-8.0#limitations Go test flight.

Got it, makes sense for it to be empty then. I still don't understand why OpenAppPackageFileAsync can't open a file on iOS though. I tried disabling hot reload but still can not see the splash screen and icon, if I understood what you suggested correctly H.A.H.

@Toto I do not suggest that you disable it. Hot reload is not just some extra feature. It is the instrument that enabled you to deploy your IOS app at first place. However, this has the limitations I linked to you. To build your application, you still need MAC. It is not optional. When you build it there, the archive is fully functional.

Damn I was not aware of that, that sucks :( Thanks a lot for getting back to me

Seems that you have solved your question. Feel free to share your solution below. Here are  some relevant docs you may refer to, File system helpers.

If you are struggling with a similar issue, like me you probably did not catch  this info:
You need a Mac device if you want to release a MAUI app on IOS.
You can still work/debug most of your iOS app plugging an iPhone to Windows which is cool but you got to get that Mac eventually.
